# Evaluating $6^2\div 2(3)+4$: is the answer $10$ or $58$?

Tags: arithmetic

Evaluating
$$6^2\div 2(3)+4$$

I understand how people are getting $10$ but I am getting $58$ because I am not distributing the $2$ to the $3$ inside the parentheses. Is that correct?

Comment: What is now the correct answer? I calculated 10. $2(3)$ were closely written together so I assumed it was the denominator of a fraction.

Comment: 58 is right according to order of operations

Comment: Don't understand that this question is that hardly downvoted.

Comment: Don't you need to calculate 2 times 3 first, since you are using parenthesis? Which overrule everything?

Comment: Is the answer not just $10$ in any way? You always need to do parentheses first, or am I wrong?

Comment: @Pedro Here the parentheses are used to represent multiplication.  The expression means $$\frac{6^2}{2} \cdot 3 + 4$$

Comment: But then you can better write $2 \times 3$. For me this makes a difference. Or when you use letters, just one after an other.

Comment: The correct answer is that it is badly written and ambiguous if there is even a question as to which it means.  Write more clearly what you mean: $(6^2/2)\cdot 3+4$ or $6^2/(2\cdot 3)+4$.

Comment: $2(3) = 2 \times (3) \neq 2 \times 3$ in this expression, because the order of operations change with or without parentheses

Comment: @Pedro: $3$ vs. $(3)$ changes no operations' order. No operations occur within those parentheses.

Comment: When plainly typed out it is no longer "ambiguous" to me. It is simple order of operations is it not? 6^2÷2(3)+4

Comment: $\div$ tends to ambiguity in cases like these. I am really not sure why it is taught still. Looking back with the knowledge I have now, I rather just be taught the more clear way from the start and use fractions for division. When I see a '$\div$' sign -  I immediately think 'low level of math'. It just notation that is not used - DOWN WITH $\div$ !

Comment: According to Matlab
`6^2/2*(3)+4` gives `ans = 58`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be written as:

$\frac{6^2}{2(3)} + 4$

$6^2 = 36$

$2(3)=6$

So now we have $\frac{36}{6} +4 = 6+4=10$

OR

$\frac{6^2}{2}(3)+4=\frac{36}{2}(3)+4=18(3)+4=54+4=58$

There is ambiguity in the way it is written - that's why it is so important to be crystal clear when writing math.

I can see you are learning basic arithmetic but down the road you will see far less of the '÷' sign and much more of expressing divisions as ratios (fractions) which removes some of the ambiguity.

Comment: Yes, a fraction would be less ambiguous but then it would defeat the purpose of testing order of operations I'm guessing. Written exactly how it is if you follow your rules PEMDAS and go from left to right you shouldn't be getting 10

Comment: How do you not get 10? the P stand for parentheses - do that first? Then you get 36/6 + 4 = 10

Comment: Yes, P does stand for parentheses but its for everything **inside** the parentheses. Not around it.

Comment: Fair enough, but M and D can be done in either order - why do you think division before multiplication is correct, and not vice versa?

Comment: @renegade05 I will upvote your answer tomorrow, I have no upvotes anymore. According to Matlab `6^2/2*(3)+4` gives `ans = 58`. Anyway, I understand that you find this a stupid question because the way it is stated, it is ambiguous.

Comment: You do not evaluated M or D before the other. You always evaluate Multiplication and Division left to right. In *this* case, the division was first.

Answer (score 1):

By the Immutable Laws of Emperor Pemdas, you square the 6 first to get 36.  Then you divide by 2 to get 18.  Then you multiply by 3 to get 54.  Then you add 4 to get 58.  You are correct. The sticky part is that the 'divide by 2' and 'multiply by 3' operations are at the same ''level'' in the empire of Pemdas so you compute left to right.

Comment: Exactly! Alot of people have the misconception that you have to Multiply first because the 'M' comes first in the PEMDAS.

Comment: misconception? why do you think D comes before M then- following your logic?

Comment: Because one has to come first.

Comment: First you calculate what is between the parenthesis. You have $(3)$ which becomes substituted by $3$. From then on, we follow the normal rules.

Comment: Left to right computation is not a valid mathematical rule, because it changes according to the meaning of the notation for division instead of being about the operation division.